# Como poner un hypervinculo en lenguague C

Tags: c, enlace

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>


int main ()

{
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("OPCIONES: A) BLACKBOARD B) SINFO");
    printf("\n\n");
    char blackboard,sinfo;
    printf("Ingrese la opcion correspondiente:");
    scanf("%c", &blackboard);

    if(blackboard == 'a'){

        printf("\n");
        printf("--- CUENTA CORREO Y BLACKBOARD ---");
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("www.google.com");
        
        getch();
        return 0;
```

}

#quisiera colocar un link en el "printf("www.google.com")", que en la consola aparesca como link , para poder dar click y se abra en el navegador

Comment: no entiendo , podrias explicarme ? uso la terminal de windows y el programa codeblock y programacion en c;

Comment: Miento. Hay 2 cosas que puedes hacer: muestra una URL correcta (`www.google.com` es un nombre de dominio; la URL sería `https://www.google.com`). Y limítate a usar las funciones de `stdio.h` para mostrar cosas (lo digo porque veo que incluyes `<conio.h>`). Con un poco de suerte, tu aplicación de consola será capaz de interpretar las secuencias correctas. Pero insisto, no depende de ti, sino de la aplicación de consola. ¡ Suerte !

Comment: crees que funcione en la consola de windows la terminal normal ? y como pondria la terminar en el printf("https://www.google.com"); ?

Comment: en linux si funciona pero en windows no funciona :( la %s  la s que significa ?

Comment: Los hipervínculos son características específicas de la web. Una terminal puede soportar su uso ... o no. Si no lo soporta, no puedes hacer nada al respecto salvo usar otra terminal diferente